# What is causing this return json() error? Python

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

If I have r.json, I expectedly get a Response [200] but its when I have r.json() that things get funky. I am very new to this so any and all tips are welcome! There is a different key found under the payload tab in chrome dev tools, and some other things I've tried plugging in like "animal_ids"

This code:

```
    data = {"key":api_key, "cookie": cookie, "start_date": date1.strftime('20%y-%m-%dT00:00:00-07:00'), 
        "end_date": date2.strftime('20%y-%m-%dT00:00:00-07:00'), "animal_ids": animal_ids
        }
    r = requests.post(url, data=data)
    return r.json()
print(icons())
```

yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\geiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\geiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\geiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\geiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\geiss\postreq.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(icons())
          ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\geiss\postreq.py", line 16, in icons
    return r.json()
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\geiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

expected yield (this is a json, no?):

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": false,
    "data": {
        "animals": {
            "9488": {
                "icons": [
                    {
                        "id": null,
                        "animal_id": "9488",
                        "color_label_template_id": "27",
                        "comment": "Can open gates 12\/8\/21",
                        "created_at": "1638992225",
                        "created_by": "120",
                        "edited_at": null,
                        "edited_by": null,
                        "is_deleted": "0",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "deleted_by": null,
                        "fontawesome_icon_id": "1495",
                        "color_label_template_group_id": null,
                        "title": "Opens Gates",
                        "color": "#ff792f",
                        "capacity": null,
                        "checkout_alert": "0",
                        "checkin_alert": "1",
                        "reservation_creation_alert": "0",
                        "owner_details_alert": "0",
                        "animal_details_alert": "0",
                        "reservation_details_alert": "0",
                        "class": "fa fa-surprise",
                        "is_pro": "0",
                        "name": null,
                        "location_id": null,
                        "animal_color_label_id": "8341",
                        "type": "custom"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": null,
                        "animal_id": "9488",
                        "color_label_template_id": "38",
                        "comment": "see employee notes",
                        "created_at": "1639781526",
                        "created_by": "137",
                        "edited_at": null,
                        "edited_by": null,
                        "is_deleted": "0",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "deleted_by": null,
                        "fontawesome_icon_id": "173",
                        "color_label_template_group_id": null,
                        "title": "Grooming",
                        "color": "#16537e",
                        "capacity": null,
                        "checkout_alert": "0",
                        "checkin_alert": "1",
                        "reservation_creation_alert": "1",
                        "owner_details_alert": "0",
                        "animal_details_alert": "1",
                        "reservation_details_alert": "1",
                        "class": "fa fa-scissors",
                        "is_pro": "0",
                        "name": null,
                        "location_id": null,
                        "animal_color_label_id": "8461",
                        "type": "custom"
                    },
```

If it helps I am specifically trying to pull the "comment" and "title"

Comment: Is your expected JSON the same as your request's output through your code?

Comment: Failing at char 0 means there was no json data. Check `r.status_code` to see if there is an error. Something outside of the 200 range.

Comment: Check what, exactly, `r.text` is. (`r.json()` is, in some sense, just a wrapper around `json.loads(r.text)`.)

Comment: @MohitGoyal Yes, I believe so

Comment: @tdelaney just returns 200

Comment: @chepner r.text is for some reason is entirely different from the expected yield?

Comment: Code doesn't care about your expectation. If `r.text` isn't valid JSON, rethink your expectation and figure out if there is a problem with the request, or if your code needs to handle the possibility of invalid JSON.

Comment: Check your working request again, replicate the same in Postman, and try around with headers. When you find out exactly what headers and payload are needed, use them in your code.

Comment: If it reports status code 200 (success) but doesn't give you any data... I'd say this API is broken. You'd expect an invalid request to have more hints than that. Maybe there is a problem with your date1 and date2, it would be worth checking whether, say, date1 is later than date2 or have some other range issue. But this may be something highly specific to whatever server you are hitting. if it has its own resources for questions, then going there may help.

Comment: For whatever reason, the remote host decided not to include any json in its response.

Comment: @chepner I am getting HTML back that doesn't carry any of the same information that dev tools says I should be getting returned in my "expected yield". I think I will try Mohit's suggestion and play around in Postman for awhile

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

to

```
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

as for POST requests, the payload is to be passed to `json` parameter, not `data`.

Comment: POST requests can use either `data=` or `json=`, it just depends on what the api expects.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I agree that `json` and `data` can both be used in a POST requests. My point is that `json` is used for passing the payload of the request